# Swift: UISearchBar cancel button animation

Tags: swift, ios8, uisearchbar

[image: any idea about the gray box?]

Any idea why there's a gray box to right of the cancel button... and how to get rid of it? (it appears when you tap in the searchbar to begin typing a search)

The SearchBar was placed in the VC through Storyboard and then connected to the VC code with an IBOutlet. Bonus points if you know how to get rid of the cancel button in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `searchBar.clipsToBounds = true`